# why does the result of shapely difference still result in overlaps?

Tags: python, gis, intersection, difference, shapely

I have a simple case of two overlapping polygons.  I want to remove the overlap between them using shapely difference.  However, when I do that, the resulting differenced polygon, still overlaps `other` -- this is not what I would expect.

[image: 1]

Here is the code:

```
In [27]: print(poly1)
POLYGON ((2007955.54219372 2487551.993107961, 2007956.914217843 2487460.06749171, 2008048.8398340936 2487460.06749171, 2008046.0957858474 2487551.993107961, 2007955.54219372 2487551.993107961))

In [28]: print(poly2)
POLYGON ((2008031.003520493 2487538.2728667296, 2008033.747568739 2487433.9990333705, 2008131.1612814823 2487433.9990333705, 2008131.1612814823 2487538.2728667296, 2008031.003520493 2487538.2728667296))

In [29]: poly1.intersects(poly2)
Out[29]: True

In [30]: poly1.overlaps(poly2)
Out[30]: True

In [31]: poly1.touches(poly2)
Out[31]: False
```

These results make sense.  However, the following results do not make sense to me.

```
In [32]: poly3 = poly2.difference(poly1)

In [33]: poly3.intersects(poly1)
Out[33]: True

In [34]: poly3.overlaps(poly1)
Out[34]: True

In [35]: poly3.touches(poly1)
Out[35]: False

In [36]: poly_int = poly3.intersection(poly1)

In [37]: print(poly_int)
MULTILINESTRING ((2008033.0615566776 2487460.06749171, 2008048.8398340936 2487460.06749171), (2008048.8398340936 2487460.06749171, 2008046.505345287 2487538.2728667296))
```

How could a difference operation possibly result in overlapping polygons?  And, if the polygons do not touch, why is their intersection a linestring?

----------- EDIT -----------

I have this expectation, because I think this fabricated case, which should be the same as the actual case above, is following Shapely's rules:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import geopandas as gpd

poly1 = Polygon([(0.0,0.0), (0.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,0.0)])
poly2 = Polygon([(0.5,0.5), (0.5,1.5), (1.5,1.5), (1.5,0.5)])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id": [1,2], "geometry": [poly1, poly2]}, geometry="geometry")
gdf.plot(facecolor="None", edgecolor="red")
```

[image: polys 1&2]

```
poly3 = poly2.difference(poly1)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id": [1,3], "geometry": [poly1, poly3]}, geometry="geometry")
gdf.plot(facecolor="None", edgecolor="red")
```

[image: polys1&3]

```
intersection = poly1.intersection(poly3)
print(intersection)
print()
print("intersects:", poly1.intersects(poly3))
print("overlaps:", poly1.overlaps(poly3))
print("touches:", poly1.touches(poly3))
```

Result:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((0.5 1, 1 1), (1 1, 1 0.5))

intersects: True
overlaps: False
touches: True
```

These are the results I would expect:

- The polygon 1 and the differenced polygon (3) share a boundary and therefore intersect and touch -- their intersection is MultiLineString
- Polygons 1 and 3 do not overlap since they have no part of their interiors in common

Comment: If 2 polygons share a boundary they overlap

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton -- I guess the Shapely User Manual is less-than-complete on that point: it suggests that overlapping polygons share part of their interior.  Even so, if two polygons share a boundary (and no part of the interior) don't they touch?

Comment: I always end up going back to the docs for this - see https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide/library/jts/dim9.html